# How to find the Property causing the exception?

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception, c#-3.0

In Linq to SQL SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueInConflict) i get Exception:

"String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

But how to figure out the Property causing this? I guess i could start testing 1 by 1 the properties but what will happen if i have numerous properties?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SP1 installed? Looks like this was fixed.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/8a81482c-194a-4a16-8c04-80a27a90e1f4/

> Great news... I installed SP1 for .Net
>   3.5 and guess what... they provide detailed information now!!!
>
> Example: "Cannot insert the value NULL
>   into column 'FullQualifiedUserName',
>   table 'WcmsDevEmpty.Users.Users';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been
>   terminated."

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Log property on your data context to be a stream (such as Console.Out or a log file) to effectively profile the SQL being executed